# Sketch the graph $x(t)[\delta(t+\frac{3}{2}) - \delta (t + \frac{3}{2})]$

Tags: dirac-delta

Sketch and label the following.
[image]

When I solve this question, I get two delta functions with the value of $-0.5$, at $t = -3/2$ and $3/2$. But the solution says it should be positive $0.5$ (aka pointing upwards.) What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How is your title related to that graph?

Comment: The graph is x(t)

Comment: The distribution $\delta(t+3/2)-\delta(t+3/2)=0$.  What are you actually trying to do here?